# Open currently running child activity from notification instead of creating a new one

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, background

I am trying to make a notification in a child activity that once clicked reopens the background activity if present, otherwise it goes back to parent activity.
The parent activity expects a result from the child activity (startActivityForResult) so I can't use launchMode singleTop or similar.

I need this because the child activity has an open connection that can't be interrupted.
The connection is retained in a fragment of this child activity with retainInstance set to true:

```
    connectionFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_CONNECTION_FRAGMENT) as ConnectionFragment?
    if (connectionFragment == null) {
        connectionFragment = ConnectionFragment.newInstance()
        fm.beginTransaction().add(connectionFragment, TAG_CONNECTION_FRAGMENT).commit()
    }
```

I've tested many solutions, but right now here's the pending intent I'm passing to NotificationBuilder setContentIntent:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    Intent(this, ChildActivity::class.java)
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
            .putExtra("notification", true),
    0)
```

As you can see I'm setting the "notification" extra so, when onCreate is called, I can detect if the activity was recreated (when findFragmentByTag returns null) and go back to the parent activity.

I'm open to find a workaround to this problem if there's no option to re-open running activity in the background.